# Css flex vertical align

Tags: css, flexbox

Hi all this is a simple tic tac toe game board made with css flex .I want to paste "X" in the vertical center of box when its hovered with using flex.This is the link
codepen.io/anon/pen/bMOmRq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css to .box

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyEeYa

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for vertical center:

```
.box:hover::before{
    content: "X";
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  height:100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```